# Ошибка линукса,что делать не знаю.Помогите!

Tags: linux, сервер

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Перезапустил систему и потом захожу в серийную консоль и тут написанно вот это помогите!Сначало когда я установил debian v7 у меня этого не было,а появилось потом.Что делать?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ваш жесткий диск поврежден. blkid пытается прочитать заголовки томов для получения информации (метка тома, UUID блока) и терпит неудачу. Это говорит о том, что жесткий диск полность не читается т.к. таблица разделов кажется уничтожена. Если вам важны данные на этом диске, то скопируйте образ диска с помощью dd, а потом попытайтесь востановить. Если нет, то просто выбросьте диск и замените на новый.
По крайней мере [тут](https://www.analyth.com/fr/touslesarticles-fr/erreur-udevd69-timeout-killing-disque-dur-defectueux/) так и советуют поступить.

Comment: А это я как сделаю?У меня дедик на азуре.

Comment: А служба поддержки Microsoft уже не работает? Они вроде должны делать бэкапы. Напишите им, пусть востановят.